# How to call a lambda on each element of a list and get the result in a new list? My working version is too verbose

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, boilerplate

I want to call a lambda function on each element of a List, and get the result in a new List.

My current version is this:

```java
b = a.stream().map(i-> i+1).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but it seems to be rather verbose and hides the intent of the code through all the boilerplate code that is needed for the transformation from list to stream and vice versa. The same code in other languages (e.g. ruby) would be much more concise, like below:

```ruby
b = a.map{|i| i+1}
```

Of course one could do something like this:

```java
for (int i: a) {
    b.add(i+1);
}
```

but it looks a bit old-fashioned, and less flexible than the lambda version.

For mutating the existing List, [Holger's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788291/why-are-java-streams-so-verbose#comment80523230_46788291) `list.replaceAll(i->i+1)` is good, but I am interested in creating a new List object.

Is there a consise way to call a lambda on each element of a list and create a new one with the result?

Comment: So that ruby programmers don't encroach on our territory. Also, we're mostly paid by character.

Comment: Your example is very simple, so using the SteamAPI is not preferable. Doing it the "old fashioned" way with a simple foreach loop is totally fine for this. As you only use primitiv ints, you can use the primitive methods of streams, which will actually reducre the character count.

Comment: You should try Kotlin instead: `b = a.map{ it + 1 }`

Comment: `list.replaceAll(i->i+1);` and you’re done. The Stream API is more verbose because it is a way more powerful tool. You wouldn’t use an industrial robot to tighten a single screw, would you?

Comment: @Korashen: So you mean to directly work with Streams without using Lists at all?

Comment: You should really learn how to work efficiently with Java 8 before you start complaining. Java is not Ruby, so don't try to write it as if it were.

Comment: And you don't use `JAVA` to generate short source code (in byte). This is really not the idea of the language...

Comment: Comparing two unrelated languages to each other and wondering why one is different from another is not a very good question. Sure, they could've left out `stream()` and done a direct mapping as `list.map()`, but instead they chose to add `stream()` which gives you a `Stream` and implemented those methods in there, instead of putting them in all `List`, `Set` and other such classes/interfaces. Java is a pretty verbose language as is, so I doubt they were counting characters in the source code when they were thinking about what the Stream API looks like.

Comment: Note that Ruby's syntax is actually quite terse compared with most other languages. See the above example in [C#](https://ideone.com/tcoSpE), [Python](https://ideone.com/C81Ns8), [PHP](https://ideone.com/7sWDiI) and [JavaScript](https://jsbin.com/dibafovegu/edit?js,console). Of these, only JavaScript is as terse as Ruby and even then it relies on very recent introductions to the language.

Comment: @Kayaman: I asked [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358575/is-it-possible-to-salvage-a-really-poorly-received-question) about this question, and people seem to agree with your feedback on the first revision of the question, but they also seem to believe that the new revision is less opinionated. I wonder if you are satisfied with this edit, and more importantly if you have an answer on how to write the above code correctly in Java 8.

Comment: I voted to reopen. Still, the best you can do is to static import `toList()`. That will cut off some clutter, but then you're left with what Java sreams offer.

Answer (score 8):

To get more concise, then you can use either some wrapper of the Stream API, or bypass it completely. You could implement something like:

```
class ListUtil {
    public static <A, B> List<B> map(List<A> list, Function<? super A, ? extends B> f) {
        List<B> newList = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
        for(A a:list) {
            newList.add(f.apply(a));
        }
        return newList;
    }
}
```

Then with static imports, you can write:

```
b = map(a, i -> i + 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

I'll ignore the comparisons to other languages, because 1. I'm less familiar with them, and 2. I think it's probably more helpful just to understand the philosophy of the language about which you're asking.

Bear in mind that lists and streams are fundamentally different things. A list (and other collection) is an entity in memory containing a finite number of elements. It contains references to all of those elements.

By contrast, a stream is a (possibly infinite) sequence of values which can be generated and consumed on the fly. There are not necessarily references to all the elements (or even any of the elements) at any given time.

Consequently, implementing "mapping" for a list is different to implementing "mapping" for a stream. For a stream, the concept is "as the elements are generated, apply a function to them, and produce the result of the function". This is supported directly by the API using `Stream.map()`.

For a list, the equivalent concept is "Give me a list whose element i is the result of applying a function to element i of the original list". This is not supported by the API, but it's easy enough to implement:

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

/**
 *  Provides a view of a source list with a function applied to each element.
 *  This list is unmodifiable.
 *
 * @param <S> The type of the elements in the source list.
 * @param <T> The type of the elements in the mapped list.
 */
public class MappedList<S, T> extends AbstractList<T> {

    private final List<S> source ;
    private final Function<S,T> map ;

    public MappedList(List<S> source, Function<S,T> map) {
        this.source = source ;
        this.map = map ;
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        return map.apply(source.get(index));
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return source.size();
    }

}
```

You would use this as follows:

```
List<Integer> original = ... ;
List<Integer> originalPlusOne = new MappedList<>(original, i -> i+1);
```

If you want the code to be more concise, you can add a static factory method to `MappedList`:

```
public static <S,T> MappedList<S,T> mapOf(List<S> source, Function<S,T> map) {
    return new MappedList<S,T>(source, map);
}
```

and then just

```
List<Integer> originalPlusOne = MappedList.mapOf(original, i -> i+1);
```

or

```
List<Integer> originalPlusOne = mapOf(original, i -> i+1);
```

if you use static imports.

Note that the mapped list is unmodifiable, so

```
originalPlusOne.add(42);
```

would throw an exception (which is appropriate, because if it succeeded it would violate the idea that `originalPlusOne` contains all the elements of `original` with `1` added to them); and note also that it is a *view* of the original list, so adding an element to `original` would add an element to `originalPlusOne`. You can of course just do

```
List<Integer> originalPlusOne = new ArrayList<>(new MappedList<>(original, i -> i+1));
```

to produce a modifiable list that is independent of the original.